# PortletURL to open another portlet in pop-up

Tags: java, popup, liferay

I have a hook for `create_account.jsp`.
In this jsp I have a javascript code where I try to open a portlet in an iframe pop-up or some pop-up from Liferay.

The question is:
How to give the portlet URL?
How can I access it?
In that portlet I only want to ask a question with YES or NO, and based on the user answer, redirect to some other page.

Answer (score 9):

1. To create a URL, you can either use `<portlet:renderURL>` or `<liferay-portlet:renderURL>`

   ```html
   <liferay-portlet:renderURL
       var="testPopupURL"
       portletName="testPopup_WAR_testPopupportlet"
       windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>">
       <liferay-portlet:param name="paramToPopup" value="customParameterToThePortlet" />
   </liferay-portlet:renderURL>
   ```

   **`portletName="testPopup_WAR_testPopupportlet"`** this is the portletId of the portlet which you want to open.

   **`windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>"`** This is important to just show the portlet in the pop-up, or else it would open the full liferay pages with navigation and all.
2. The javascript which you can write in your JSP to use the above URL and open the popup and the portlet within:

   ```js
   // this is one of creating function
   function <portlet:namespace />showPopup(url) {

       var url = url;

       // this is one way of calling a pop-up in liferay
       // this way is specific to liferay
       Liferay.Util.openWindow(
               {
                   dialog: {
                       cache: false,
                       width:800,
                       modal: true
                   },
                   id: 'testPopupIdUnique',                
                   uri: url
               }
           );
       }

   // this is another way of creating a function in liferay
   Liferay.provide(
           window,
           '<portlet:namespace />showAUIPopUP',
           function(url) {
               var A = AUI();

               // this is another way of calling a iframe pop-up
               // this way is not specific to liferay
               popupDialog = new A.Dialog(
                   {
                       id: 'testPopupIdUnique',
                       centered: true,
                       draggable: true,
                       resizable: true,
                       width: 800,
                       stack: true
                   }
               ).plug(
                   A.Plugin.DialogIframe,
                   {
                       uri: url,
                       iframeCssClass: 'ogilvy-dialog-iframe'
                   }
               );

               popupDialog.render();
           },
       ['aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe']
   );
   ```
3. You can simply call these javascript functions something like this:

   ```html
   <a href="javascript: <portlet:namespace />showPopup('<%=testPopupURL%>')">
       Popup using Liferay open-window
   </a>

   <a href="javascript: <portlet:namespace />showAUIPopUP('<%=testPopupURL%>')">
       Pop-up using Alloy UI dialog
   </a>
   ```
4. The portlet which would be displayed inside the `iframe` of the pop-up either should have `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>` in `liferay-portlet.xml` as:

   ```html
   <portlet>
       <portlet-name>testPopup</portlet-name>
       <icon>/icon.png</icon>
       <instanceable>false</instanceable>
       <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
       <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
       <css-class-wrapper>testPopup-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
       <!-- This property is necessary otherwise you would see a "Access denied for portlet" message when you try to open this portlet dynamically -->
       <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
   </portlet>
   ```
5. Or should have the property `portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist` in `portal-ext.properties` as:

   ```
   portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist=3,56_INSTANCE_0000,58,82,86,87,88,103,113,145,164,166,170,177,testPopup_WAR_testPopupportlet
   ```

To check out this code in action you can download 2 portlets from and refer to the instructions in [this liferay forum](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/19129386).

Hope this helps in understanding liferay better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the renderURL tag. In the JSP just put a form and make the treatemnet you want with your MVCPortlet Class.

```
<portlet:renderURL var="myPopuURL"windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/myJspWithYesOrNo.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<script>
   my_function_to_open_popup_with_url('<%=myPopuURL%>');
</sricpt>
```

Note that Liferay provides a way to create popup with AUI:
http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/alloy-ui/demo?title=community-liferay-projects-alloy-ui-demos-dialog