# Portlet in a modal dialog box

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2 server for developing a web application.
Some of the functionality needs to be presented in modal boxes. 
Is it possible to make a portlet behave like a modal dialog box or if is there any way a portlet can be put in a modal dialog box? 
I spent a lot of time searching for some documentation but couldn't find any. 
Any input or a reference is much appreciated!

I want to have a JIRA like functionality... 
- when you click on 'create issue' button, it is a pop up in portlet, isnt it?

Wondering how can i have the same behavior?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266725/portleturl-to-open-another-portlet-in-pop-up

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Liferay 6.1, I have not tested in 6.2.

In your JSP:

```
<liferay-portlet:renderURL
var="myPopUpURL"
portletName="myPortletName_WAR_myPortletNameportlet"
windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>"
<liferay-portlet:param name="myParamName1" value="myParamValue1" />
<liferay-portlet:param name="myParamName2" value="myParamValue2" />   
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<% myPopUpURL="javascript:showPopup('"+myPopUpURL+"')"; %>

<aui:button value="Show PopUp" onClick="<%=myPopUpURL %>"/>

<aui:script>
function showPopup(url) {

var url = url;

    Liferay.Util.openWindow(
        {
            dialog: {                   
                width:800,
                centered: true,                 
                resizable: false,
                title: 'MyTitle',
                modal: true
                /* there are many other options... */
            },
            id: 'myPopUpId',                
            uri: url
        }
    );
}
</aui:script>
```