# Make dynamically added portlet have the same scopeGroupId as calling portlet

Tags: liferay, ipc, liferay-6, portlet

#### Problem

When showing a portlet (say test-portlet) in pop-up through a link in another portlet (say abc-portlet), the `scopeGroupId` shown in the test-portlet is always the groupId and not the page-scope-id or scopeGroupId which is configured for abc-portlet.

More details follow, if the problem is not clear.

Basically what I have done is what is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279195/468763). Will give the brief below.

#### What we have done

1. Created a custom portlet - test-portlet
2. Have made that portlet scopeable `<scopeable>true</scopeable>`
3. Have also added - `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>`
4. This works fine as intended even with page-scope
5. We have another portlet - abc-portlet
6. same configuration as test-portlet
7. this portlet also works fine

#### What we are doing and what is happening

1. We are calling test-portlet in a pop-up from abc-portlet
2. This works
3. Now we change the scope of abc-portlet to page (say Home)
4. Now when we access the test-portlet the scope shown in test-portlet is still Liferay (i.e. the Guest group) and not Home as set in abc-portlet.

#### Question

1. Is there any more configuration so that test-portlet can pick-up the scopeGroupId same as abc-portlet
2. Is there anything possible I can change in the code which can tell the test-portlet to use the scopeGroupId of abc-portlet i.e. make test-portlet aware of the scope of abc-portlet?

Any pointers in the direction will be of great help.

**Environment:** Liferay 6.2 EE bundled with Tomcat

Thanks

**Note:** Have also cross posted this on [Liferay Developer Forum](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/46618454).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some searching finally found out how liferay does it. The hint came from the source code in [ServicePreAction](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/events/ServicePreAction.java#L470):

```
if (!group.isControlPanel()) {
    doAsGroupId = 0;
}
```

Liferay uses this functionality in `Related Assets` for adding a blog, wiki, document, folder etc while adding or editing an asset, so checked the JSP *`/html/portlet/asset_browser/toolbar.jsp`* to see how the URL is made.

Liferay's steps are similar to what I wanted to do:

1. Give a link to open the asset portlet (for eg: Blog) to add an entry.
2. The pop-up which opens has the same scopeGroupId as that of the underlying portlet (for eg: Documents and Media)

One would think that the attribute `doAsGroupId` is just fit for this scenario. Yes it is essential but alone it does not suffice and surprisingly the other attribute which is essential is `plid`. By default `plid` will be the current page/layout the user is on and the URL would be made with respect to the current page but this default value does not help.

The `plid` needs to be set to the plid of `Control Panel`!

Here is the sample renderURL we write in the abc-portlet to open test-portlet in the pop-up, notice the attributes `doAsGroupId="<%=scopeGroupId %>" and plid="<%=controlPanelPlid %>"` of `<liferay-portlet:renderURL`:

```
<%
long controlPanelPlid = PortalUtil.getControlPanelPlid(company.getCompanyId());
%>

<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="testPortletURL" portletName="test_WAR_testportlet" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>"
        doAsGroupId="<%=scopeGroupId %>" plid="<%=controlPanelPlid %>" refererPlid="<%=plid %>">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="referringPortletResource" value="abc_WAR_abcportlet" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<%
String testPortletURLJavascript = "javascript:Liferay.Util.openWindow({dialog: {destroyOnHide: true}, id: 'test', title: 'Test Portlet View', uri: '" + HtmlUtil.escapeJS(testPortletURL) + "'});";
%>

<h4><a href="<%=testPortletURLJavascript%>">Click here to open test portlet in pop-up</a></h4>
```

Wonder why liferay thought of using `plid="<%=controlPanelPlid %>"` instead of just the `doAsGroupId` which seems pretty straight-forward.

**Note:** I also discovered that if we use `plid="<%=controlPanelPlid %>"` we don't need to have `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>` in `liferay-portlet.xml` which is essential if the resource needs to be dynamically added.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: If there is any other much easier way, I am up for it. Thanks

Comment: That's strange why would not the `doAsGroupId` work alone, why should it need the control-panel layout? May be because a layout is already inside a particular group and it can't work differently, that can be said for Control panel also but we all know Control Panel is very special ;-)